# finding specific type of list in ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

lets say I've a wardrobe i can put list, list,..

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> wardrobe
```

Then i want to list items of specific type.

if i say list all my shirts,

i thought of

```
public <T> ArrayList<?> getAllItems() {
    for (ArrayList<?> itemList : wardrobe) {
        Iterator<?> iterator = itemList.iterator();
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
            Object next = iterator.next();
            if(next.getClass().equals(T)) return itemList;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

1. but its an error! am i missing anything (misunderstood the generics concept?)!
2. How can i achieve that?

i thought of calling

```
<Shirt>getAllItems();
```

Comment: @DineshKumar if you are working somekey like T-Shirt-> List you can use HashMap<String,ArrayList<T>>

Comment: why evn bother using generics in this case?  why not simply `ArrayList<ArrayList>> wardrobe`

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood: yeah thats fine! but how do i retrieve particular type of list from that?

Comment: does instanceOf not work?

Comment: @Octopus unexpected Type required:class found T if i use instanceof and cannot find symbol if i compare using getClass().equals(T)

Comment: Does each list inside the main list have a consistent type inside (eg, is it a list of shirts, a list of jackets, a list of hats and so on), or does each list have a variety of types of object inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method definition like this

```
public <T> ArrayList<?> getAllItems(Class<T> clazz) {
    for (ArrayList<?> itemList : wardrobe) {
        Iterator<?> iterator = itemList.iterator();
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
            Object next = iterator.next();
            if(next.getClass().equals(clazz)) return itemList;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

then, call `<Shirt> getAllItems(Shirt.class);`

Hope this helps!

Comment: T classType as paramter too worked! but what does class<T> mean?

Comment: Generic informations are erased at runtime, it cannot be recovered. A workaround is to pass the Class<T> in parameter. It just a Class of generic type T. But, its ugly ;)

Comment: why its said to be ugly?

Comment: Instead of T.class, you have to pass it as Class<T> class everywhere you need to know the class of the generic type.

Comment: any other suggested way?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work, because the inside of the method does't really know what `T` is (because Java generics work by type *erasure*). Instead, you should either:

- Rely on the generics system to enforce things for you and stop trying to check them, or
- Pass in the explicit class that you're searching for. (This would also help if you were looking for a `Cat` class and `T` was `Animal`, assuming that `Cat` is a subtype of `Animal`.)

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> getAllItems(Class<T> clazz) {
    for (ArrayList<?> itemList : wardrobe) {
        Iterator<?> iterator = itemList.iterator();
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
            Object next = iterator.next();
            if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(next.getClass()))
                return (ArrayList<T>)itemList;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You'll need to suppress some warnings here, as the cast is formally unsafe, but it will be OK provided each list in `wardrobe` really is of a single type of element (or at least that they don't have a shared superclass).

Comment: is Class<T> and T clazz same?

Comment: @Dineshkumar Yes, and it's how you tell the method what T actually is, since this is a case where it actually needs that information.

Comment: i can't assign the result back to ArrayList<Shirt> !

Comment: Sorry if i have paramter as (T classType) then its error

Comment: @Dineshkumar Well, it works when I test it with Java 7, so I don't know what problem you're hitting with it…